# Base class in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a lot of generic methods in my program that take some generated entity as parameter. So, methods like:

```
public void DoHerpDerp<EntityType>()
```

While this is fine and does the job, users of my methods can still pass whatever they want as generic parameter (and crash the application). I want to strictly limit them to entity generated objects (I'm using Database First approach). What I want to write is something like:

```
public void DoHerpDerp<EntityType>() where EntityType : BaseEntity
```

Is there such class as BaseEntity, and if the isn't one, how do I work around this? And no, I'm not gonna write 200 partial classes that implement an interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could change the generation of the entities by adapting the T4 template.

Here is the relevant part of the T4 template (e.g. `Model.tt`) for generating the class declaration, e.g. "`partial class MyEntity`":

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        _code.Escape(entity),
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
}
```

to

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}{4}",
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        _code.Escape(entity),
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)),
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType))) ? _code.StringBefore(" : ", "BaseClass") : "");
}
```

In this example, every class which has no super-class is generated as a sub-class of `BaseClass` which you may implement as you wish.